# Drawing a circular arc in glsl

Tags: glsl, shader

I already know how to draw a circle. But I'm really stuck on how to actually make it an arc. In the end I would like to be able to specify the start and end angle. Then the arc should start from the bottom, offset by the start angle, and then go until the end angle is reached.

This is how I drew the circle:

```
vec2 uv = textureCoords * 2.0 - 1.0;
float distance = sqrt(dot(uv,uv));
float OD = 0.7;
float ID = 0.5;
float ODC = smoothstep(OD, OD - 0.01, distance);
float IDC = smoothstep(ID, ID + 0.01, distance);
float alpha = ODC * IDC;
if(alpha < 0.001)
    discard;
FragColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, alpha);
```

I then tried to fiddle around with:

```
float g = uv.y / dist;
float sector = 0.5 - g / 2.0;
```

But I cant seem to get the mapping quite right...

Answer (score 0):

```
float angle = (atan(uv.x, uv.y) + pi) / (pi * 2);
if(alpha < 0.001 || angle < 0.25 || angle > 0.5)
    discard;
```

Got it, but maybe someone has a better solution.